# piping cut output to another cut command is not working

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use cut command to extract the value  but piping cut return value to another cut is not working

for example below one works

```
cat content.txt | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

but this one

```
cat content.txt | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '-' f 1
```

doesn't work and returns

```
usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]
```

Comment: BTW, as an aside, it's much more efficient to run `tail -1 content.txt` than `cat content.txt | tail -1`. When you make `tail` read from a pipe (or other FIFO), it has to read all the way from the start of the stream, whereas when you give it direct access to the file, it can skip right to the end. If you're dealing with large files, that difference can be enormous.

Comment: thanks. yes. it make sense. i will modify the script.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `f 1` instead of `-f 1`. This error made `cut` believe than `f` and `1` are filenames, and it complained because it was not told *what* to cut since neither `-b` (bytes), nor `-c` (characters), nor `-f` (fields) was given.